# How can I check if input is written in a random number?

Tags: html, button, random, input, numbers

Hi how can I check with what in the input I am writing this code and I want to check if the input is written with
The random number (one) every time I press the thank you button

```html
<p id="one" ; style="color:#01FF4B;font-size:50px;font-family:heebo thin"></p>
<button style="background-color:#404040" onclick="random();" ; class=""><p style="color:#01FF4B;font-family:heebo thin;font-size:25px">Next Number</p></button>

<input type="text" name="num" value="" style="">


<script>
  function random() {

    document.getElementById("one").innerHTML = Math.floor(Math.random() * 999) + 100;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: You are already generating a random number here. What is your desire exactly?

Comment: I want to check if input is written the random number every time I click the button to take action. thank again:)

Comment: The random number is **always** written to the `#one`. Why should it not? This is the concept of programming. The only possibility when it doesn't happen is, when the `#one` does not exist. So you can do `var o = document.getElementById("on"); if(o !== null){...}`

Comment: I think what OP is trying to ask is how to check if the value of input (num) is the same as the generated random number. If that is so, you can attach an event handler to the `input` event of the input field and check if the value is the same as the random number in one. An one liner could look like this: `<input type="text" name="num" oninput="function(event){if((document.getElementById('one').innerHTML == event.target.value}){alert('correct!')}" >`. Note that I did not check correctness of the syntax.